# How to find the nth derivative given the first derivative with SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy, differential-equations

Given some *f* and the differential equation *x*'(*t*) = *f*(*x*(*t*)), how do I compute *x*<sup>(*n*)</sup>(*t*) in terms of *x*(*t*)?

For example, given *f*(*x*(*t*)) = sin(*x*(*t*)),
I want to obtain *x*<sup>(3)</sup>(*t*) = (cos(*x*(*t*))<sup>2</sup> − sin(*x*(*t*))<sup>2</sup>) sin(*x*(*t*)).

So far I've tried

```
>>> from sympy import diff, sin
>>> from sympy.abc import x, t
>>> diff(sin(x(t)), t, 2)
```

which gives me

```
-sin(x(t))*Derivative(x(t), t)**2 + cos(x(t))*Derivative(x(t), t, t)
```

but I'm not sure how to tell SymPy what `Derivative(x(t), t)` is and have it figure out `Derivative(x(t), t, t)`, etc. automatically.

---

### Answer:

Here's my final solution based on the answers I received below:

```
def diff(x_derivs_known, t, k, simplify=False):
    try: n = len(x_derivs_known)
    except TypeError: n = None
    if n is None:
        result = sympy.diff(x_derivs_known, t, k)
        if simplify: result = result.simplify()
    elif k < n:
        result = x_derivs_known[k]
    else:
        i = n - 1
        result = x_derivs_known[i]
        while i < k:
            result = result.diff(t)
            j = len(x_derivs_known)
            x0 = None
            while j > 1:
                j -= 1
                result = result.subs(sympy.Derivative(x_derivs_known[0], t, j), x_derivs_known[j])
            i += 1
            if simplify: result = result.simplify()
    return result
```

Example:

```
>>> diff((x(t), sympy.sin(x(t))), t, 3, True)
sin(x(t))*cos(2*x(t))
```

Comment: You should post your answer separately from your question.

Comment: @Fermiparadox: It's not really my answer, it's just a description of what I gathered from the other answers. I didn't want it to take away potential votes from existing answers...

Comment: @Mehrdad you should still post it as an answer. It doesn't take away votes (you are allowed to vote on multiple answers).

Comment: @asmeurer: I meant people might vote up my answer instead of theirs because it's better (people often just vote for the best answer) even though it's based on theirs. I don't see the point either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one approach that returns a list of all derivatives up to `n`-th order

```
import sympy as sp

x = sp.Function('x')
t = sp.symbols('t')

f = lambda x: x**2 #sp.exp, sp.sin
n = 4 #3, 4, 5

deriv_list = [x(t), f(x(t))]  # list of derivatives [x(t), x'(t), x''(t),...]
for i in range(1,n):
    df_i = deriv_list[-1].diff(t).replace(sp.Derivative,lambda *args: f(x(t)))
    deriv_list.append(df_i)

print(deriv_list)
```

> `[x(t), x(t)**2, 2*x(t)**3, 6*x(t)**4, 24*x(t)**5]`

With `f=sp.sin` it returns

> ```
>  [x(t), sin(x(t)), sin(x(t))*cos(x(t)), -sin(x(t))**3 + sin(x(t))*cos(x(t))**2, -5*sin(x(t))**3*cos(x(t)) + sin(x(t))*cos(x(t))**3]
> ```

EDIT: A recursive function for the computation of the `n`-th derivative:

```
def der_xt(f, n):
    if n==1:
        return f(x(t))
    else:
        return der_xt(f,n-1).diff(t).replace(sp.Derivative,lambda *args: f(x(t)))

print(der_xt(sp.sin,3))
```

> `-sin(x(t))**3 + sin(x(t))*cos(x(t))**2`

Answer (score 3):

Declare `f` and use substitution:

```
>>> f = diff(x(t))
>>> diff(sin(x(t)), t, 2).subs(f, sin(x(t)))
-sin(x(t))**3 + cos(x(t))*Derivative(sin(x(t)), t)
```

Comment: Substitution doesn't work generally. Try replacing `2` with `4`.

Comment: yea. you mean somethiing like automatic conversation of every integral and deifferential? no such thing on sympy. you need to tell it you want the representation substituted by some predefined function, otherwise it will always want to convert to full representation. also, `f` is a function. not some integer. it replaces the core sympy expression in the evaluated expression.

Comment: I think substitution should actually work fine if SymPy only used first derivatives (i.e. didn't convert `Derivative(Derivative(x(t),t),t)` into `Derivative(x(t),t,t)` automatically). Is there no way to tell it that either?

Comment: they do not specify such way, and i think it goes against their build of the classes. as i tested it, it automatically transform the `Derivative(Derivative(x(t),t),t)` into `Derivative(x(t),t,t)` (when typing it in shell)