# nth derivative with sympy

Tags: python, sympy, derivative

I'm a bit new to sympy
I would like to compute nth derivative of an expression using sympy; however, I don't understand how the `diff` function works for nth derivative:

```py
from sympy import diff, symbols

x = symbols("x")
f = ((x**2-1)**5)

# for n = 2
# from the sympy docs, I do:
d_doc = diff(f, x, x)

# using the diff two times
d_2 = diff(diff(f, x), x)
```

I get two different results:

```py
>>> d_doc
10*(x**2 - 1)**3*(9*x**2 - 1)

>>> d_2
80*x**2*(x**2 - 1)**3 + 10*(x**2 - 1)**4
```

`d_2` is the correct answer in this case.

Why is this?
is there a way to make a function that takes a `n` and returns the nth derivative?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the nth derivative given the first derivative with SymPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324336/how-to-find-the-nth-derivative-given-the-first-derivative-with-sympy)

Comment: Simplify them. They're both the same. `d_doc.simplify()` gives: `(x**2 - 1)**3*(90*x**2 - 10)`. So does `d_2.simplify()`

Comment: As for _"Is there a way to make a function that takes a n and returns the nth derivative?"_ `diff(f, x, n)` is the same as writing `x, x, x, ..., x` n times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in an easy place, (from Pranav Hosangadi's comment):

It is the same, diff(f, x, x) simplifies the expression

```py
>>> simplify(diff(f,x,x))
(x**2 - 1)**3*(90*x**2 - 10)
>>> simplify(diff(diff(f,x),x))
(x**2 - 1)**3*(90*x**2 - 10)
```

Comment: For additional information, one can use `diff(f,x,n)` in order to directly get n-th derivative. For example, `diff(f,x,5)` would be equivalent to `diff(f,x,x,x,x,x)`.